# Is there a "player of the year" award for international basketball?

Tags: basketball, awards

The international governing bodies of some sports give an official "best player of the world" award. For example,

- FIFA (association football): [FIFA Ballon d'Or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_Ballon_d%27Or)
- FIH (field hockey): [FIH Player Of The Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_Ballon_d%27Or)
- IRB (rugby union): [World Rugby Player Of The Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Rugby_Player_of_the_Year)

Does FIBA, the international basketball federation, give a similar award?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Edits (pending) clarify the question as it was implicitly meant, referring to an equivalent POTY given by FIBA, and all but stated by @Pablo in comments. Please *don't* vote as "too broad" when there can be only one answer to whether a single group does a specific thing!

Comment: @nij with the comentaries and edition, it came clear to me that the governing body for basket is FIBA. Now looking a bit in google I found a recently new award they give (since 2005) "FIBA Europe Player of the Year Award " . Still dont know if there is the same award but for people of any nationality, which would be the equivalent of the golden ball in soccer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the lack of anyone finding any evidence, I'm going to go out on a not very big limb and say "No, FIBA does not give a 'best player in the world' award".

The closest that seems to exist is that FIBA *Europe* give a "[Player of the Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIBA_Europe_Men%27s_Player_of_the_Year_Award)" award. This is open to any player with European citizenship, but mostly goes to players in the NBA.

Answer (score -3):

When in NBA a team wins a championship they are called the best in the **world** (world champions, because in NBA are playing the best players from different countries). So I guess when somebody is awarded as MVP (most valuable player), he is the best in the world.

Comment: The question was clarified some time ago to mean a FIBA award. The NBA, like other sports in the USA, call things "World" players, leagues, series, etc. because of exceptionalist social tradition, not anything to do with the origin of players.

Comment: But you cannot argue with the fact that in NBA there are the best players in the world

Comment: Some of them, yes. But if all players in the world were ranked, a substantial number of NBA players would be below some number of players from elsewhere.